# How to persist changes made to Rails view rendered at client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have a view that allows user to modify the rendered HTML, such as move the buttons around, changing the colors of a DIV etc. How can I persist those changes such that when the view is rendered next time, those changes are reflected?

My first thought was to store the modified HTML into database as a text column. However I really don't like this approach since the HTML can be arbitrarily large, not to mention performance will be very bad. I dug around and so far haven't a clue, which is puzzling to me since I don't think this is that rare of a scenario: WYSIWYG type editor, website builder application should all need to solve this problem. Which makes me wonder if I'm going down the wrong track.

Any insights are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found a solution, which is:

1. create a model called 'Site'
2. break a page into multiple logical parts, such as logo/header, navigation menu, content etc.
3. edit the page WYSIWYG-style
4. save the HTML into DB via this model
5. when the page needs to be rendered to reflect the changes, pull out the contents from DB and render them 'raw' in the template

Answer (score 0):

To to this you need to give some position numbers to your buttons. After moving those buttons around call the ajax request to store those positions in serialize manner in the database or in the cache.

```
  [button3, button1, button4, button2] or "button1, button4, button3, button2"
```

By looping this object (convert this object into an array ) you can display those buttons when next you render the view.

Same you can do it with div's color. Give some unique ids to your divs and store those ids with color-code.

I hope this will help you a little-bit.

Comment: Thanks Santosh. I have two problems with this approach:  1. sounds like the new changes will be applied after the view is rendered next time, IE user will see the old page first, then the new one, which makes kind of bad user experience. I would like a way to fully integrate the changes so that it becomes part of the view 2. it feels like a little bit over-engineering to design a data structure to store all kinds of DOM changes, which would not be easy at all, from what I can tell

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the user has lots of control over the DOM, so it doesn't make sense to store changes on a per-element basis - that'd be impossibly difficult to maintain and hugely inefficient.

The user will be updating both HTML and CSS, and those are essentially just strings, so a good solution may be to render the modified HTML and CSS as strings and store them in MongoDB documents (either together or separately), then reference those Mongo documents when you want to load up the page again.