# How to persist dynamic views?

Tags: dom, reactjs, webview, persistence, virtual-dom

I am using .NET MVC 4. Let's say I have a Pinterest-style social media site. Users can pin content (ie., images), and decide the layout of their pinboard by dragging/dropping images around the board.

How do I persist the layout they've made so that when they log-out/log-in, the content appears exactly as before? All DOM elements with associated IDs, classes, styling, etc. need to be saved. I would need to "auto-save" these layouts as well.

The best answer I could find was this one:

[How to persist changes made to Rails view rendered at client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206986/how-to-persist-changes-made-to-rails-view-rendered-at-client)

But this fellow seems to be saving the actual HTML mark-up. I think that will become very inflexible very fast. I thought I should be persisting the DOM tree itself, or possibly take the ReactJS route for designing my views, assuming ReactJS lets me save its VirtualDOM (or an instance of the actual DOM) to a database that it can then re-render upon log-in.

What am I missing? I've searched high and low for this but with out much luck on how to solve this problem. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could just store metadata about your view in order to recreate it. It's hard to tell what your exact requirements are, but dashboards are typically pretty flat, meaning you could just store an array of objects for each image, and information about those images. I think storing the dom / virtual dom sounds like an interesting experiment but not totally necessary.

Comment: Yes it sounds like you're probably right. My idea to store the DOM may just be overkill, and it seems like the better approach is to save some collection of objects representing the content (images).